# Why my media query for 768px and 576px not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying media queries, but they won't work on 768px and 576px. I tried the minimum width but it also does not work.

```css
.changing-color {
  background-color: powderblue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vh;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .changing-color {
    background-color: chartreuse;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .changing-color {
    background-color: blueviolet;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .changing-color {
    background-color: brown;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .changing-color {
    background-color: darkorange;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .changing-color {
    background-color: darkkhaki;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="changing-color"></div>
```

Comment: What color do you see?

Comment: the color i dont see is dark orange and dark khaki

Comment: I see darkkhaki on screen <= 576px and darkorange on screen <= 768px, it works. If you see something else, you can make a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: is it because i am using internet explorer that i dont see darkkhaki and darkorange?

Comment: @sylvia_fe it depends on the width of the viewport you are using. Are you resizing your window?

Comment: yes i am using inspect element to see it, okay thank you i will try it

Comment: @sylvia_fe try resizing your window. In inspector you can choose to view it as 'mobile' or other formats. This will show the different colors because the window will be smaller width. Your CSS rules will change the color based on the width of the screen.

Comment: These aren't "Bootstrap media queries". They're just media queries and custom CSS.

Comment: Are you saying that some of these work and some don't?

Comment: I tried to test your code with the Internet Explorer 11 browser and it works fine. You could check my test result [here](https://imgur.com/a/ULLQl01). Let me know if I missed something. Note: After you open the link, click on an image it will enlarge it and play the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is correct, it works in this pen. Maybe you are not resizing your screen? Because that is exactly what these media-queries are for.

This snippet below is limited in width, so it will show probably darkorange depending on how you are viewing this page. On mobile it might even show darkkhaki.

```css
.changing-color {
    background-color:powderblue;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 30vh;
    font-size: 3vw;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1400px){
    .changing-color {
      background-color:chartreuse;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .changing-color {
      background-color:blueviolet;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 992px){
    .changing-color {
      background-color:brown;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .changing-color {
      background-color:darkorange;
    }
  } 

   @media screen and (max-width: 576px){
    .changing-color {
      background-color:darkkhaki;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="thing changing-color"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a viewport meta tag like this ?

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

> This is needed because by default, most mobile browsers lie about their viewport width.

Reference  [Beginner's Guide to Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries)